# Thieves guild blindsighted/Under new management

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I completed 5 radiant quests/jobs for Delvin/Vex and completed all 4 special quests (Silver Lining, Summerset Shadows, The Dainty Sload, and Imitation Amnesty) but I still haven't gotten the Under New Management quest. I equipped the Thieves Guild armor and tried talking to Bryjnolf but he just says he's busy. I did about ten more jobs  and no new quests came up. I checked in my completed quest and I have completed the special quests. I don't know if I'm missing something or it's a glitch.

I think what I need to know is how to get either Blindsighted or Under New Management but I'm not sure how to start a new possible quest. I don't know about the thieves guild main quest line and where I am on that but I need help to progress to get the final quest for the Skeleton Key and becoming the leader of the Thieves Guild. I have not met Karliah if you might have asked but I'm not sure what I do to meet her or continue on the main questline for the thieves guild.

So I'm basically trying to progress forward in the Thieves Guild so I can become a Nightingale. (I believe i am on the next quest in the main quest line after "Loud and Clear") but I can't seem to and if anyone can help me it would mean a lot. Use my information that I gave to help you.

Comment: What do you mean by "the 4 special quests"? Are you trying to say that you've completed Trinity Restored with Karliah and are now a Nightingale but aren't getting the next quest?

Comment: So you know the 4 quests you get from doing the radiant quest called- the dainty Sload, summer set shadows,  imitation amnesty, and silver lining, I completed all of those but yet I still didn't get the under new management quest.

Comment: As Jim Jones' answer says, you need to complete all the main quest-line. If you haven't met Karliah, you haven't completed it.

Comment: I think I'm on the dampened spirits quest because I have completed the Loud and Clear quest but dampened spirits isn't there. I don't think I ever got the quest and I don't know how

Comment: Are you on PC or Console?

Comment: I'm on console Xbox 360

Comment: Today I tried talking to brynjolf but he didn't give me a quest and still kept on saying he was busy. I asked him in the ragged flagon and even did reparations but there was still no luck

Comment: Ok, I think I have it figured out. To speak to brynjolf, maven black briar can't be the jarl which she is for me right now. I think I have to complete the civil war set of quests but mine is glitches and I can't get the jagged crown because I can't go into the dungeon because there is no entrance where legate Rikke is. When I wait or leave, they seem to get in fine but I can't find a door or passage way

Comment: @Matthew_m321 go along the stairs to reach a door. Make sure it isn't the locked door.

Comment: @JimJones didn't see a door or stairs and the entrance is caved in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to complete the Thieves' Guild questline before starting Under New Management. After completing the questline, complete as many jobs and complete the special jobs too. After completing 4 of them, talk to Brynjolf to start the quest. Blindsighted is part of the questline. Try reloading a save tht's as not as far beyond your point.

Comment: The thing is, I have already talked to him severa times but he keeps saying he is busy. After I finished the final "special quest" I didn't get the under new management quest to I'm not sure if it's a bug or I didn't do something right

Comment: you know the 4 quests you get from doing the radiant quests called- the dainty Sload, summer set shadows,imitation amnesty,and silver lining, I completed all of those but yet I still didn't get the under new management quest. Bryjnolf does say anything to me, I wasn't wearing the thieves guild armor when I was completing the final quest and bryjnolf vex or delvin never say anything new to me. I haven't gotten far enough to see Karliah, and I only completed 11 guild quests. (If the radiant quests/ jobs count, I'm just saying I did much more than 11 quests. Bryjnolf is just standing by a wagon

Comment: I think I did something very wrong. I didn't complete the main quest line before getting the special quests

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a glitch I can't get through now that I think about it

Comment: I really can't reload a save because I have made very much progress since the loud and clear quest. (Literally almost 40 levels, 10 daedric artifacts, leadership of TDB, Companions, Completion of the main quest, and a lot more.)